# Using the same SUIT for more than one try in a class with defined "with"-statement

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, with-statement, code-reuse, staleelementreferenceexception

I am currently automating ui-tests via selenium in python and some webElements are changing periodically which leads to StaleElementReferenceExceptions.

My current solutions for such troublesome elements is, to use try-except-blocks with a for-loop encasing them.

```
    for _ in range(numberOfTries):
        try:
            webElement = get_theNeededWebelement()
            doSomethingWithWebElement(webElement)
            break
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass
    else:
        raise Error(specificErrorText)
```

I would like to be able to just define the numberOfTries and the specificErrorText together with the block within the try-statement and transfer the reusable logic into a class.

Something to use like this:

```
with StalenessExpector(numberOfTries, specificErrorText):
    webElement = get_theNeededWebelement()
    doSomethingWithWebElement(webElement)
```

Is there a way to do something like that?
Maybe with recursion or a proper "with"-statement?

Comment: Please do not edit questions with solutions. This is what answers are for. If you found a solution in another question then please flag this one as a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer elsewhere:

It seems that it isn't possible to access the code within the with statement.
The thing I wanted to achieve is possible via passing a codeblock to a function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405968/how-could-i-pass-block-to-a-function-in-python-which-is-like-the-way-to-pass-blo)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).